# Find the smallest upper limit of $\pi$+$\pi$_written_backwards

Tags: limits

Find the smallest upper limit of $\pi$+$\pi$_written_backwards.

(As an example, assuming the approximation $\pi=3.1415$ then $\pi$_written_backwards=5.1413, by definition.)

I said like this:

$\pi$+$\pi$_written_backwards<$\pi$+9.999999999....

Yes, but 9.999999999.... is a rational number while, I guess, $\pi$_written_backwards is not, being smaller than 9.999999999....

Any idea?

Comment: So... letting $\pi_n$ be $\pi$ written to $n$ decimal positions and $\overline{\pi_n}$ be the "reverse" of $\pi$ written to $n$ decimal places, you ask what $\limsup\limits_n\{\pi_n+\overline{\pi_n}\}$ is?  Well... if $\pi$ turns out to be normal (*which has not been proven yet but is expected to be true*) then there will always be $n$'s with longer and longer sequences of $9$'s at the truncated end of $\pi_n$ regardless how far along you go... so yes, the answer to your question would appear to be $\pi+10$

Comment: Why is $\pi$_written_backwards not rational? If I understand the question correctly, all of them should be rational.

Comment: @JMoravitz your comment should be an answer in my opinion

Comment: @supinf $\overline{\pi}$ (*pi written backwards*) is not a well defined concept.  The limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \overline{\pi_n}$ using my notation above does not exist.  Rationality aside... *existence* of the "number" is a far bigger problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Is the rationality of the limit something you're concerned about for answering the question, or just an observation you've made?

Comment: For the little we know, who can exclude that after $10^{10000}$ digits $\pi$ becomes a sequence of $000000000000\ldots$ with some $1$ here and there?